# My teacher claimed that this code block is run in O(n) time... why is that?

Tags: c, time-complexity

My teacher claimed that this code block will take O(n) time to execute. I'm trying to figure out why. I realize that the two for loops bundled together would be an arithmetic series ..... my logical approach was if K = 3, then the inner loop would run three times, then two times, and then once. If K = 2, then the inner loop would run twice, once, and then stop .

In mathematical terms, it would be N, N-1, N-2 for k = 3

I was later able to use the arithmetic series formula and got N*(N + (N-(N-1))/2..

I don't know how to approach the while loop.

All I can surmise is that when N =4 , the loop runs twice and until N = 9, the loop runs thrice... How would I set this up mathematically?

The end result is N*(N+(N-(N-1)))/2 + O(while loop) to get O(N)?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
void doit(int n) {
     int k = 0; int m = n; int s = 0;
     while (m <= n) {
         k = k + 1;
         m = k * k;
     }

     for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
         for (int j = i; j < k; j++) {
             s = s + m;
             m = m - 1;
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as you can see the while loop and the nested for loop are separate of each other. Therefore we'll calculate the time complexity for each one separately.

## While Loop

Inside the while loop we have instructions that are independent of `n`. The problem here is how we calculate the number of times the while loop runs. If we 'cheat' a bit and look at it in terms of `k` instead of `n` we notice that at once we exit the loop, `k` holds the number of times the loop has ran for. It's just like having a counter really. At that point `k^2` is roughly equal to `n`therefore the complexity is `O(sqrt(n))`

## For Loops

Here's where the real magic happens as this part will turn out to be `O(n)` overcoming the `O(sqrt(n))` complexity of the while loop.

---

The time taken by each `for` loop can be seen as a sum of a constant number of instructions. Therefore we'd have a nested sum. I'll try to describe it for you as StackOverflow won't let me post images. You basically have two sums, one starting with `i=0` and going up to `(k-1)` and another starting from `j=1` and going up to `(k-1)` and all you're adding is a constant number `c` of commands.

You can easily calculate this sum and it turns out that the complexity is `O(k^2)` but again we have to think in terms of `n` and just like before it becomes `O(n)`.

Answer (score 5):

The loops itself are `O(k^2)`, but the thing is what comes before it. The `while` loop finds the smallest square number `m = k^2` that is larger than `n`, so basically because `m` relates to `n` the end result becomes practically `O(n)`.